# How can we get the status of WiFi /Bluetooth on Android using C# client libraries in Appium?

Tags: c#, android, appium

With the help of Appium C# libraries, I am trying to get the status (or perform on/off action) of Bluetooth / Wi-Fi from Android devices programmatically(not by going through Settings page and checking the status or performing the actions).

I know it can be done through ADB commands like "adb shell svc wifi enable" but it requires root permissions.

Basically I am looking for alternative to NetworkConnectionSetting class in Java.

Does anybody have any idea how can this be achieved through C#?